# Twitter Rate limit on other devices

Tags: android, twitter4j

Heads-up! im new to twitter4J

I'm in the process of developing an Android application that involves using twitter api 1.1
I just ran into a pretty big problem. The app works great but im afraid that if i install it on too many devices that it will stop due to the rate limit. I want to show the latest tweet from a desired user. 
My code...

```
 try {
                    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                    Paging paging = new Paging(1, 2);
                    Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();



                    List<Status> statuses;
                    statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("User...", paging);
                    for (Status status : statuses) {
                        text = status.getText();
                        time = status.getCreatedAt();
                        userName = status.getUser().getScreenName();


                    }
```

I there a way i can get above code to work without having to go for OAuth option, or is there another way???

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

I know i am answering this very late,

- In the version `1.1` of twitter api, No calls can be made without using `access_token` and `token_secret`.
- Regarding rate limits, there are two initial buckets available for `GET` requests: 15 calls every 15 minutes, and 180 calls every 15 minutes. Refer [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits) for more details.